# Adding a dollar sign in front of currency

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

```
select ( (select price from fruit where name = "apple") * sum( quantity )))
as "value of apples" from inventory
where fruitID = (select fruitID from fruit where name = "apple");
```

The output gives me the value of apples but without the $ in front of it. I know I need to add the concat function somewhere but I cannot figure out where it goes.

Where do I add `(concat("$", )` ?

Comment: Provide some sample data and expect result,that really help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are way more subqueries than are needed.

Also, if the `name` column in `fruit` is not unique, the query has the potential to throw a "too many rows" error.

If `name='apple'` can match more than one row in `fruit`, we might want something like this:

```
 SELECT f.fruitid
      , f.name
      , SUM( f.price * i.quantity ) AS `total value`
      , CONCAT('$', SUM( f.price * i.quantity ) ) AS `dollar total value`
   FROM fruit f
   LEFT
   JOIN inventory i
     ON f.fruitid = i.fruitid
  WHERE f.name = 'apple'
  GROUP
     BY f.fruitid
```

If we want a combined value of all `fruit` that match, then something like this:

```
 SELECT SUM( f.price * i.quantity ) AS `total value`
      , CONCAT('$', SUM( f.price * i.quantity ) ) AS `dollar total value`
   FROM fruit f
   LEFT
   JOIN inventory i
     ON f.fruitid = i.fruitid
  WHERE f.name IN ('apple','pear','pineapple')
```

---

This doesn't address formatting to two decimal places. If we want a formatted value to two decimal places and including thousands separators, we could make use of the MySQL `FORMAT` function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you need use `JOIN` instead of subquery.

Your subquery is no make sense.

`concat` function can combine multiple string.

> CONCAT(str1,str2,...)

I think you can try this.

```
select concat('$',f.price * sum(inv.quantity)) as "value of apples" 
from inventory inv
INNER JOIN fruit f on inv.fruitID = f.fruitID
where f.name = "apple";
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dde7b/3*

[Concat Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select ( concat('$', (select price from fruit where name = "apple") * sum( quantity ))) as "value of apples" from inventory where fruitID = (select fruitID from fruit where name = "apple");
```